# flutter checkboxListTile is not getting checked in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, checkbox

I am using CheckboxListTile to check the items instead of checkbox. I want to fetch data of selected Items. All works fine. I am getting the expected data but the state of checkbox is staying the same it is not changing...

```
 List selectedItemsList = [];
  List checkListItems = [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "value": false,
      "title": "Sunday",
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": false,
      "title": "Monday",
    },
  ];
```

```
 Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: checkListItems.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              bool? isChecked = false;
              return CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text(checkListItems[index]['title'].toString()),
                  selected: isChecked,
                  value: isChecked,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      isChecked = value;
                      print(isChecked);
                    });
                    if (selectedItemsList.contains(checkListItems[index])) {
                      selectedItemsList.remove(checkListItems[index]);
                    } else {
                      selectedItemsList.add(checkListItems[index]);
                    }
                  });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change checkListItems value, not the isChecked:

```
// first change isChecked
bool isChecked = checkListItems[index]['value'];

// then inside setState change
setState(() {
    checkListItems[index]['value'] = value;
});
```

now it can update

[image]